# Realm Swift: Handling/preventing sync error 108

Tags: swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've been testing the new platform over the last couple weeks and have had trouble with syncing reliability, occasionally getting an error 108 inside the SyncManager.sharedManager error handler. I see from the documentation that error is described as:

“Client file bound in other session (IDENT)” Indicates that multiple sync sessions for the same client-side Realm file overlap in time.

However, I'm not really sure what this means or how to go about debugging it. Any advice?

**solved... maybe?:** I found there is a logOut() method in the RLMSyncUser class which seems to flush any open sync sessions. I've added this to my error handler which will hopefully reset sync states.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with older Realm Object Server versions, but has been fixed since version [1.0.0-BETA-2.2](https://github.com/realm/realm-sync-services/releases/tag/v1.0.0-BETA-2.2). Please update to a newer version of the Realm Object Server. [1.0.0-BETA-4.2](https://github.com/realm/realm-sync-services/releases/tag/v1.0.0-BETA-4.2) currently.